# Crawl through all sheets in an XLS with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a large volume of XLS files. Within a sheet in the files, it contains a column header of "name" and "number". Unfortunately the format of each XLS varies and the name of the sheet that the data is in varies from one file to another.

I am able to parse through a sheet using Python 2.7x to extract the data from specific columns what I'm now looking to do is open each XLS file and work out which sheet contains the headers "name" and "number" before then extracting the data within these columns and importing to a MySql.

Any suggestions of how to do this or libraries to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XYPath](https://github.com/scraperwiki/xypath) might be worth a look - it lets you query XLS files for the contents of tables, including by the names and contents of columns.